# Meteor Client Side External Javascript File issues

Tags: javascript, meteor, external

I'm playing with pubnub and Meteor and I'm referring to a client side external js file and receiving errors.

My code is below. The server side is working well however the client side is receiving the error. "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '$' of undefined"

I have this working well in nodejs but want to get it to work in Meteor. Been pulling my hair out on this one for a while, thanks.

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {

  // counter starts at 0
  Session.setDefault('counter', 0);

  Template.hello.helpers({
    counter: function () {
      return Session.get('counter');
    }
  });

  Template.hello.events({
    'click button': function () {
      // increment the counter when button is clicked
      Session.set('counter', Session.get('counter') + 1);
    }
  });

  Template.hello.rendered = function(){

    $.getScript("http://cdn.pubnub.com/pubnub.min.js", function() {
    //callbcak function
      (function(){
        var output = PUBNUB.$('output');
        PUBNUB.subscribe({

          channel: 'my_channel',
          callback: function(message){
            output.innerHTML += message;
          }
        })
      })();
    })
  };

}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    // code to run on server at startup
  });

  var PUBNUB = Meteor.require('pubnub').init({});

  setInterval(function() {
    PUBNUB.publish({
      channel: 'my_channel',
      message: 'hello SMB'
    });
  }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: I should have also stated that the error is on this line. var output = PUBNUB.$('output');

Comment: well, where do you define PUBNUB? you seem to only define it on the server.

Comment: PubNub is defined in the js file.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you haven't initialized the instance!

```
var pubnub = PUBNUB({
    subscribe_key: 'your-sub-key',
    publish_key: 'your-pub-key' 
});
```

Then,

```
pubnub.subscribe({...
```